# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Book_ID') using node.js and express,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app written in node.js and express.js and The app runs correctly when all files are into the app.js

```
(venv_tour) 192:data michellejativa$ npm start 

> pkg_tour@1.0.0 start
> node app

==>Server started (http://localhost:3000/) !
Successful connection to the database 'tour.db'
Successful creation of the 'Books' table
Successful creation of 3 books
```

The app.js file includes all the source code. I have started splitting routes within app.js
For example for Book.js,

```js
//Books.js
//Here we will import the route /books
//which is locate into /routes/Books.js
const booksRoute = require('./routes/Books');
app.use('/books', booksRoute);
```

The Book.js source code is as follows:

```js
// Books.js

// Set router
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
// Import db
const db = require('../db.js');

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM Books ORDER BY Title";
        
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
        res.render("books.ejs", { model: rows });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

using /books works perfectly.

[image]

When I split the source code for Edit.js where a record identified by the :id parameter must be edited, I get the error:

```
TypeError: /Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/views/edit.ejs:6
    4| <h1>Update a record</h1>
    5| 
 >> 6| <form action="/edit/<%= model.Book_ID %>" method="post">
    7|   <div class="form-horizontal">
    8| 
    9|     <%- include("_editor") -%>

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Book_ID')
    at eval ("/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/views/edit.ejs":15:32)
    at edit (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:274:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/routes/Edit.js:36:13)
    at Statement.replacement (/Users/michellejativa/Documents/allAboutNodejs/pkg_tour/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:25:27)
```

This is the first time I split the source code for a route that requires a parameter like :id

The source code of Edit.js is as follows:

```js
// Edit.js
// Set router
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
// Import db
const db = require('../db.js');

// GET /edit/5
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Book_ID = ?";
    
    db.get(sql, id, (err, row) => {
        // if (err) ...
        res.render("edit", { model: row });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

From app.js the code that includes the /edit path is the following:

```js
//Edit.js
//Here we will import the route /edit:id
//which is locate into /routes/Edit.js

const editRoute = require('./routes/Edit');
app.use('/edit/:id', editRoute);
```

Apparently the problem is in the line of code:

```js
res.render("edit", { model: row });
```

When I use /edit/:id from app.js the edit works perfectly.

```js
// GET /edit/5
app.get("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Book_ID = ?";
  db.get(sql, id, (err, row) => {
    // if (err) ...
    res.render("edit", { model: row });
  });
});
```

Any guide to fix this error would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil- After editing the Edit.js file and adding {mergeParams:true} to the code, const router = express.Router( { mergeParams: true } ); the /edit path works perfectly. Thanks!